# Is it possible to define transduration for frames created with allowframebreaks?

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

is there any way to define transduration for the whole bibliography? The following doesn't work, just the first of the created frames has the expected behavior.

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
  \transduration{2}
  \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
  \bibliography{literature}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: The command `\transduration` accepts overlay specs such as `\transduration<2>{1}`. Can you try with different overlay options such as `<2-4>` or `<2->`? You might also want to move its position down as the last item in the frame.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But unfortunately this doesn't work either.
I tried both to put it at the end of the frame or to put some overlay options. But in my opinion overlay options aren't a good idea here, because [allowframebreaks] says: Overlays are not supported.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense I've overlooked it apparently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Mico pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51238/3323), `\transduration` is designed to work with overlays of a single frame, not between several frames. It is reset at the beginning of each new frame, so that's why it has no effect when used on frames split with `allowframebreaks`.

To overcome this, `\transduration` has to be repeated on each frame. This can be done by adding it to the `background canvas` template:

```
{
\addtobeamertemplate{background canvas}{\transduration{2}}{}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
  \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
  \bibliography{literature}
\end{frame}
}
```

The curly braces are for keeping the redefinition local, otherwise every frame following the bibliography would also be shown only for two seconds.

#### Example presentation

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  My \uncover<2>{Presentation}
\end{frame}
{
\addtobeamertemplate{background canvas}{\transduration{2}}{}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
  \lipsum
\end{frame}
}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \lipsum
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

<sub>(The [`lipsum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) package is used to generate dummy text for making a self-contained example. You can remove it and replace `\lipsum` with your own bibliography, of course.)</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot! Makes sense, that the default way of adding `\transduration` does not work with splitted frames.
But nice to see that there is a solution for such a problem.

Comment: Did you just placed a *virus* in the background canvas? :-)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the short answer to your question is, sadly, "No".

A slightly longer version of the same answer: `\transduration` can be applied to overlays of a frame; if no overlay is specified, the `\transduration` macro applies to the entire frame. Note that there's no provision for making the macro apply to consecutive frames. Now if you use the `allowframebreaks` option to break up some longish material that won't fit into a single frame (such as a bibliography) into several separate frames, beamer is creating separate frames and not separate overlays of the same frame. The beamer package's [user guide](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) notes this fact explicitly on p. 59: "You can use the option `allowframebreaks` to cause the [frame environment's material] to be split among several slides, though you cannot use overlays then." And since you cannot use overlays, the `\transduration` command has no chance of achieving what you'd like it to do.