# Global transition effect in beamer

Tags: beamer

Is it possible to set a global transition effect for all frames instead of specifying the effect again for each frame?

Comment: Yes. There is a work around in @diabonas answer below. `\addtobeamertemplate{background canvas}{\transfade[duration=2]}{}`

Comment: This works perfectly in Xreader on Linux

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: no.

The longer answer is that the way the `frame` environment is set up in `beamer` deliberately resets the transitions and buries this deeply within the code. That reflects the original author's position that transitions should be used sparingly and for single frames only. Altering this behaviour would require a significant rewrite of parts of `beamer`.

Comment: I'm not questioning the developers design choices, but of course there are use cases where a global option is useful. I guess I'm going for a massive search & replace then :) Thanks for the info, saved me a lot of time.

Comment: If I were starting from scratch, this is something I would make available as an option: however, I'm very wary of making major changes to `beamer` at this stage.

Comment: @JosephWright It would be a nice feature. It is hard to add effect for every frame separately and adds a lot of same code which is a bad attitude. Please consider adding this feature in future. Thanks.

Comment: @sajjadG As I said in a comment, without more-or-less starting from scratch this would be very hard. Also, though, I do sympathise with Till Tantau's position: slide transitions should really not be used for every slide.

Comment: Sorry, but that seems hard to believe. Below, we can see a workaround. And I can imagine that one could also create a new option or command that (re-)applies those options to every slide, no?

Answer (score 11):

As a workaround similar to the one provided in [Is it possible to define transduration for frames created with allowframebreaks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51260/3323), you can add the transition effect to the `background canvas` template so that it is reactivated automatically after each reset:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Add global transition effect \transfade
\addtobeamertemplate{background canvas}{\transfade}{}

\begin{document}
\frame{\centering\Huge1}
\frame{\centering\Huge2}
\frame{\centering\Huge3}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

An other way is to use [impressive](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/)  for your presentations. This software allow you to add transition effect between pages of your pdf.