# beamer - global transition shifts slide content

Tags: beamer, transition

Using beamer with the [mtheme](https://github.com/matze/mtheme), I want to have a global transition effect (a fast fade) which I set using the following code:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{background canvas}{\transfade[duration=0.2]}{}
```

as found on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123003/136196) answer.

However, doing it messes up with my slides settings. It doesn't change every slides, only the `\section` ones that are slightly shifted to the right, adding a white line on the left, as seen here:
[image: Ugly white shift on the left of the slide]

I tried using XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, as they are the only compilers I could use for my current font, but they both have the same issue.

It probably comes from the theme, however I have no clue why it would happen or how to fix it.

Edit : [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{m}
\addtobeamertemplate{background canvas}{\transfade}{}

\begin{document}
\section{test}
\end{document}
```

Requires the mtheme to work

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I just added the MWE, as you can see it is really just about adding the `\transfade`.

Comment: From the link to GitHub that you provide: `IMPORTANT NOTICES FOR VERSION 1.0 The package and theme name changed from **m** to **metropolis**!`

Comment: Same happens with default theme and a background color, so it's not a `mtheme` problem. As [Joseph Wright said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122957/1952) in cited question, what you want is not possible and the proposed workaround is just a workaround that doesn't work on all situations.

Comment: By the way, `metropolis` theme is already in CTAN: http://ctan.org/pkg/beamertheme-metropolis

Comment: @Ignasi So you think my issue is not something we can deal with? As there is no frame for `\section`, how could it be modified if not with default values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the problem is a missing `%` in the beamer definition of

```
\newcommand\beamer@dotrans[2][]{%
  \def\beamer@transdir{}%
  \def\beamer@dur{}%
  \setkeys{beamertrans}{#1}%
  \edef\beamer@temp{{pdfpagetransition={#2 \beamer@transdir\space\beamer@dur}}}% <- This one is missing
  \expandafter\hypersetup\beamer@temp}
```

(this had been fixed in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/b7a4383535e9b534c822fdbe039369ce6044724f)

---

A quick workaround: add your transition at the end of the background canvas template, not at the begin:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[background=dark]{metropolis}

\addtobeamertemplate{background canvas}{}{\transdissolve[duration=0.2]}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{test}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```