# White vertical line on the Metropolis theme background

Tags: beamer, backgrounds, beamer-metropolis

I am using Beamer's Metropolis theme which is freely obtained in [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/13669062vntrmhgrbtcj#/52868575/). The problem is that if I add the line

```
\addtobeamertemplate{background canvas}{\transfade[duration=1]}{}
```

to obtain effects in the presentation, in the PDF document there is a white line on the left side as you can see in this image

[image]

How I can avoid this?

I have used the following code, suggested by @samcarter

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme[background=dark]{metropolis} 
\addtobeamertemplate{background canvas}{\transfade[duration=1]}{} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame} abc 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

But the result is the same

[image]

Comment: Looks like a very small sidebar?

Comment: Yes. A thin vertical white line appears, it looks like a small bar. But it should not be there.

Comment: @GalCubo What is the purpose of having `\transfade[duration=1]` in the background canvas?

Comment: @GalCubo Can you add a MWE that reproduces the problem? `\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[background=dark]{metropolis}
\addtobeamertemplate{background canvas}{\transfade[duration=1]}{}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{frame}
 abc
\end{frame} 
 
\end{document}` works fine for me.

Comment: @samcarter I think you can find an answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22412/beamer-transition-effect.

Comment: @GalCubo I know what the transition effect does :) However I am wondering why you want to add it to the background canvas?

Comment: @samcarter Ahhh, I understood your question.  Well, I've only done what is said here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130071/how-to-change-global-slide-transition-effect-duration-in-beamer/130074

Comment: @samcarter The idea is to make the transition effects apply to the entire document.

Comment: @samcarter I used your code and the problem persists

Comment: @GalCubo How are you compiling? With pdflatex or something else? Which tex distribution do you have?

Comment: @samcarter I compile using XeLaTeX to load the sources of the theme. That's what you mean? Use TeXLive 2017. I think it's the most current

Comment: I think I've found the same question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375065/beamer-global-transition-shifts-slide-content/375111

Comment: @samcarter The answer is just to type \addtobeamertemplate{background canvas}{}{\transfade [duration=1]}, instead of \addtobeamertemplate{background canvas}{{\transfade[duration=1]}{}. A subtle difference!

Comment: @GalCubo As I wrote in the answer you linked to, this is only a workaround - the real answer is to update your tex distribution.